# c++11 friend of pure virtual class can't access private methods

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using `g++ 4.8.4`.
A friend `Friend` of pure virtual class `Derived` cannot access `Derived`'s private methods, unless the pure virtual function declared specifically.
Code:

```
class Friend;
class Base {
private:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base {
private:
    friend class Friend;
};

class Friend {
public:
    void doSomething() { derived->doSomething(); };
private:
    Derived* derived;
};
```

Compilation gives the following error:

> error: ‘virtual void Base::doSomething()’ is private

What fixes the error is specifically declaring `doSomething()` for `Derived`:

```
class Derived: public Base {
private:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    friend class Friend;
};
```

Why?
Should it act like that?

Comment: You gave `Friend` access to `Derived` and the compiler complains about you accessing `Base`. Seems pretty straightforward. Give `Friend` access to `Base` or restrict `Friend` to not use `private` parts of classes other than `Derived` and `Friend`.

Comment: The method is private in Base. Derived cannot call it, and neither can its friends. However Derived still can override it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `doSomething` is declared as `private` in `Base`. This means that not even a derived class can access it. Move it to `protected` and it should work:

```
class Base {
protected:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};
```

Also, since `Derived` doesn't implement the function, it too, will be considered an abstract base class (you cannot make an instance).

Comment: Oh, I feel shame. Thanks!